# C# How to replace " by . using String.replace()

Tags: c#, string

can't belive my self strugling on this but :

I would like to use the method [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) to Replace " by . in a string

**Example :**

Input : 6"1

**Desired Output :** 6.1

Code

```
var w = WeighList.Items[WeighList.SelectedIndex].Replace(""", ".");
```

Comment: You simply need to escape `"`: `.Replace("\"", ".")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Replace('"', '.')`

Using single quotes makes it a char literal instead of a string literal.

If you did want to use a string, you would need to escape the quote `"\""`